# Show that the function $g: \mathbb{R}^{2} → \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g (x, y) = f (αx + βy)$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous. Show that the function $g: \mathbb{R}^{2} → \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $g (x, y) = f (αx + βy)$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I made a demonstration by absurdity, but I don't know if it is easier to demonstrate this directly using only the definition of uniform continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then, according to the assumptions of the question, there exists a $\delta>0$, such that
$$
|x-y|<\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon
$$
Now suppose that 
$$
|(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)|=\big((x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2\big)^{½}<\delta'
$$
then
$$
|(ax_1+bx_2)-(ay_1+by_2)|= |a(x_1-y_1)+b(x_2-y_2)|\le (a^2+b^2)^{1/2}\big((x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2\big)^{½}<(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}\delta'
$$
Hence,
$$
|(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)|<\frac{\delta}{(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |(ax_1+bx_2)-(ay_1+by_2)|<\delta \\
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(ax_1+bx_2)-f(ay_1+by_2)|<\varepsilon.
$$
Note. We have assumed that $a^2+b^2\ne 0$. If this is not given, then we could define
$$
\delta'=\frac{\delta}{(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}+1}
$$
to avoid vanishing denominators.

Answer (score 1):

You observe that $r: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ that maps $(x,y)$ to $\alpha x +\beta y$ is uniformly continuos, but the uniform continuity is stable under the composition, so

$f\circ r$ is uniformly continuos.